# Directly select shortest match in Active Directory tools' object picker UI

Tags: active-directory

Let's say I want to make a User account a member of 3 groups through the object picker of the AD tools (the "Select Groups" window), and that I add in the "Enter the object names to select"  box/field the names of 3 groups, the lookup of which won't result in unique objects...

Example: I want to add the User account to:
*SupportGroup Application01 User*
*SupportGroup Application02 User*
*SupportGroup Application03 User*
which all exist but there also happen to exist the following groups:
*SupportGroup Application01 User - Admin*
*SupportGroup Application02 User - Admin*
*SupportGroup Application03 User - Admin*

Is there a way to make sure it will directly resolve only to the names we provided (that is, the shortest matches)?

For instance, that it directly selects *"SupportGroup Application01"* without making me choose between it and *"SupportGroup Application01 User - Admin"*?

Separating each name by semi-colons, or enclosing them in quotes doesn't help...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way. You expect too much from Microsoft's simple GUI.

---

It would have helped had you provided any use context (ie. description of what you need this for). As far as you're the clicking guy, I'd generally say PowerShell does the trick much faster than UI *and* allows wildcards the way you need them:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(name=SupportGroup Application* User)" | Add-ADGroupMember -Members <myobject>
```

Or, if you're operating on a specific plaintext list separated with semicolons, try this one:

```
"Group 1;Group 2;Group 3" -split ";" | Get-ADGroup | ADGroupMember -Members <myobject>
```